# SaveChanges is not working on modify the data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

when i try to save the the new Student object. it works fine but when i am trying to modify the data, it doesn't update the data. Instead none error is thrown on SaveChanges.

i am using code first approach (using mysql provider) and here it is the complete source.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e34frntq8u5gsmh/SchoolManagementSystem.rar?dl=0

my tired code is this :

```
public ActionResult Create(Student student, HttpPostedFileBase Image)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    student = db.Students.Find(student.ID);
                    if (student.ID > 0)
                    {
                        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;                        
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (student.Basic == null) student.Basic = new BasicInformation();
                        if (Image != null && Image.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            student.Basic.PictureUrl = Image.FileName;
                            string path = Server.MapPath(("~/Images/"));
                            Image.SaveAs(path + Image.FileName);
                        }

                        db.Students.Add(student);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("StudentList");
                }
            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

Comment: It appears to me that when you are overwriting your student variable coming back from the website with this line `student = db.Students.Find(student.ID);`.  Therefore, you are overwriting your updated model with the one you already had.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the modify scenario :

```
if (student.ID > 0)
                {
                    db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;                        
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Eliminate this line of code :

```
db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

and instead add code that updates the object with the new modified values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Marius. 

I tried by eliminating the db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified; but still not worked

Answer (score 1):

By this line

```
student = db.Students.Find(student.ID);
```

you overwrite the `student` that enters the method and you lose all changes. You can do two things in stead:

1. Only remove the line. Your code will now attach the modified `student` as `EntityState.Modified`.
2. Fetch the original student from the database and copy the modified values to it:

   ```
   var studentOrg = db.Students.Find(student.ID);
   db.Entry(studentOrg).CurrentValues.SetValues(student);
   ```

(both `SaveChanges` calls can be moved to one just before `return RedirectToAction...`)

Option 1 will generate an update statement containing all `Student`'s fields, but not have a roundtrip to get the original record.

Option 2 has this roundtrip, but only updates modified fields. This (option 2) can be beneficial when changes are audited or when concurrency should be minimized.

Comment: Hi.Thanks Gert and tommy. i checked it with 
 var studentOrg = db.Students.Find(student.ID);
db.Entry(studentOrg).CurrentValues.SetValues(student);                                            
                        db.SaveChanges();
But still no error comes up .Save Changes didn't throw any error but still data is not being saved.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking to the right database afterwards? Can be tricky with localdb (if you use that).

Comment: Can you please modify my source and analyse the issue. I think it would be a better approach for diagnosing the issue

Comment: Honestly no, I haven't got time to do that. *If* you use localdb it probably gets overwritten every time you run your app (this is usually the case when `SaveChanges` is successful but no data seem to have changed). Use SQL Express in stead.

Comment: Thanks Gert for helping me. i updated my post now. please see now. i think i have a concurrency issue now.

Comment: OK, but this is not the recommended way to deal with questions at StackOverflow. Your original problem was spotted and solved. If any new problems appear after applying the fix you have to ask a new question. The Q&A should stick to the original subject. This is also for your own benefit, because a new unanswered question will attract far more viewers.

Comment: OK Gert i submit the new post now.